# debian10 не подключается к wifi сети

Tags: linux, debian, администрирование, wifi

В общем чистая система подключил внешний wifi  адаптер по usb сети видит но не подключается.

Comment: Часто производители хотят калибровочный файл подсунуть, где описаны кое-какие настройки радио-модуля и не только. Внизу ответ в правильную сторону.

Answer (score 2):

Добавь non-free репозитории. Установи пакеты firmware-realtek, firmware-atheros посмотри какой нужен для твоего адаптера.

Детальней если посмотреть dmesg после вставки адаптера то бывает пишет что ему не хватает.

Если нет возможности использовать те, что поставляет дистрибутив, или в дистрибутиве нет нужной версии, есть ещё вариант.

Сборка со всеми firmware есть тут https://github.com/q3aql/drivers-linux-firmware

Архив большой, в зависимостях `rsync` https://packages.debian.org/buster/rsync

Comment: Какие репозитории, инетом не могу пользоваться как только система установилась, я утратил возможность пользоваться инетом, во время установки он работал,

Comment: телефон подключи кабелем к компьютеру и включи режим USB-модема

Comment: Не работает, все тот же сбой при подключении

Comment: вайфай выключи когда пробуешь с телефоном.

Comment: @Gybernaty Загрузитесь с лайва, с которого ставились, примонтируйте разделы и скачайте.

Comment: @Gybernaty добавил ссылку на пак всё в одном. попробуй через него поставить.

Comment: @Oxyd пока ставилось - работало на фирмвари которую загрузила в адаптер винда, шанс что с лайва стартанет не велик

Comment: @eri Ну попробовать никто не мешает.

Comment: Все что вы тут написали я пробовал и без вас, простите)))), есть дельные предложения?

Comment: @Gybernaty это не отраженно в вопросе) теперь начнем с начала. Dmesg, lspci, lsusb